# How to get orderid in redirect url page while integrating ccavenue in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment-gateway, ccavenue

avenue in my website with integration kit they provided. I am able to make payment and amount is credited in my merchant account.
I am using `redirecturl.php` for getting response

submit form to ccavenue

```
<form method="post" name="redirect" action="http://www.ccavenue.com/shopzone/cc_details.jsp"> 
<?php
echo "<input type=hidden name=encRequest value=$encrypted_data>";
echo "<input type=hidden name=Merchant_Id value=$merchant_id>";

?>

</form>
```

Redirecturl Page

```
error_reporting(0);
    $workingKey='xxxxxxxxxxx';      
    $encResponse=$_POST["encResponse"];         

    $rcvdString=decrypt($encResponse,$workingKey);      
    $AuthDesc="";
    $MerchantId="xxxxxxx";
    $OrderId=$_GET['link'];
    $Amount=0;
    $Checksum=0;
    $veriChecksum=false;

    $decryptValues=explode('&', $rcvdString);
    $dataSize=sizeof($decryptValues);
```

> I want to know how to pass order id amount and other details to redirecturl page.??

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an form to redirecturl page so you can just add another input element which value to send via POST ( must be inside form tags you are sending )

```
echo "<input type='text' name='your_form_input_name' value='' ";
```

And in your redirect page you access it via input name assigned before

```
$variable=$_POST["your_form_input_name"];
```

Comment: my form is submitting to ccavenue site `action="http://www.ccavenue.com/shopzone/cc_details.jsp"`

Comment: What else you want to pass on this site? I think they should have an API for explaining what variables you can pass and what you can receive